# How to predict future position of an object(bullet sync)?

Tags: physics, box2d, projectile-physics, movement-prediction, extrapolation

There is a multiplayer game and server sends to all clients a message when a shot happens, containing bullet position, bullet velocity and timestamp. By having timestamp, we can calculate the lag, let's say it's 100ms.

My game uses Box2D. How can I predict the real and current bullet position by having such data? I guess velocity might also change a little bit too.

Answer (score 1):

`current_position = starting_position + ((lag_delay + time_elapsed ) * velocity)`

Where "time elapsed" is how long we've known about the bullet existence.  Ostensibly this doesn't need to be stored, as when the bullet is created client-side, it is 0, and afterwards we update its position every frame update.

The lag delay is merely just an extra bit of deltaTime applied when the bullet is first spawned.

Comment: I guess this only works for linear, straight line bullets. What about ones that  are affected by gravity?

Comment: Calculate the gravity for the lag_time as well.  Seriously, all the lag_time is is a once-off "do this much movement as the bullet spawns" calculation.

Comment: can you provide an example please?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/vuCsZc3B